# Improve performance time on SVM ( low-spec pc )

Tags: python-3.x, performance, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Low specs laptop user here ( Intel Core i3 CPU M 380 @2.53GHz, 2.0 GB RAM )

I have 40,000 rows of data with 277 columns for machine learning prediction, with following code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score, KFold

temp1 = pd.read_csv("dataset_feature_vector_champion_number_dummy.csv")
dataset_champion_number = temp1.iloc[:,0:276]
target = temp1['winner']

SVM = svm.SVC() #still blank

def tenfold_cross_validate(classifier_name, dataset, target):
    validate = KFold(len(target), 10, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
    score = cross_val_score(classifier_name, dataset, target, cv=validate)
    print(score)
    print("mean score: %s" % (str(np.mean(score))))

tenfold_cross_validate(SVM, dataset_champion_number, target)
```

I'm running it on IPYNB and it didn't show any results at all. Only a deprecation warning cause i used "cross_validation" before "model_selection".

I switch to Notepad++ and running it on CMD, for starter i used only 20 rows of entire dataset. It shows result (of course, duh)

Then i turned back to real dataset, 3 hours and still no result...

Next step i'm trying to only use 1/10 of the datasets and still not get the result i wanted.

So, aside from my low spec laptop... Can i improvise the code by using any other means ?

1. How does comparison of SVR and SVC fare in this ?
2. Which kernel is better and faster ?
3. I have another method that is Naive Bayes which i haven't tried using this method, will it face this kind of problem too ?
4. Note that i have 6 features, another one with 150 columns and the rest is just 11 column. If i have to reduce my datasets for each feature, i can reduce it 25.000 based on my quality data selection, 10 - 15 thousands if i'm forced to...
5. If this help, i can do borrow someone laptop with 4GB RAM, i5

For the worst case, i'm willing to spend at most 24 hour for execute time with 2 method of prediction and 6 features dataset.

Comment: (1) You are not even tuning params, so what's the point of this huge (10 folds) CV? (2) Kernel-SVM is slow, especially with many many rows! (3) Observe memory and make sure this is not a bottleneck. If it's not, increase kernel cache-size. (4) Check if your features are sparse if so, check if your data-type used is sparse. (5) In multi-class case, think carefully about OvR vs. OvO approaches. (6) Naive Bayes is completely different and probably not that dependent on the number of rows complexity-wise.

Comment: i haven't know yet about tuning parameters, i need to learn it some more. Thank you for the rest of your answer, well noted !